# database schema for document revision

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I have a schema that I'm trying to normalize:

```
Component
( component_id
, component_number
, component_revision
, ...
)

Component_lot
( component_lot_id
, component_lot_number
, component_number
, component_revision
, ...
)

Component_supplier
( component_supplier_id
, component_supplier_name
, component_number
)
```

Ideally I'd like to get rid of the component_number in both the component_lot and component_supplier tables, as well as the component_revision in the component_lot table, and just use component_id.

The problem is that when the component revision is changed, I have multiple entries in the component table for the same component number, and I have to find a good way to determine which revision is active (it's not a simple 1, 2, 3 numbering system that I can sort by, and it's possible that a new revision could exist but not be active yet).  Additionally, if I create a new revision of a component, it gets a new id and now I have to establish the supplier for the new revision of that component in component_supplier.

I've considered making an isActive field in component, but that doesn't seem like an effective solution to the problem.  I've also considered keeping component_number as the fk in component_supplier, but there are instances where the component number could change (rare, but possible).

Any advice or links to articles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Normalizing

From your story I've understood that component_number is an entity in it's own, so:

```
Table Component_Numbers
( component_number_id /* PK */
, component_number
)

/* UK: component_number */

Table Components
( component_id /* PK */
, component_number_id /* FK to Component_Number */
, component_revision /* Descriptive. */
)
/* UK: component_number_id + component_revision */

Table Component_Lots
( component_lot_id /* PK */
, component_id /* FK to components. */
, component_lot_number /* Descriptive. */
)
/* UK: component_lot_number */

Table Component_Suppliers
( component_supplier_id /* PK */
, component_supplier_name /* Descriptive. */
, component_number_id /* FK to component_numbers. */
)
/* UK: component_supplier_name + component_number_id */
```

Suggestion: to keep column names short and clear, I recommend `id` instead of `component_supplier_id` etc. When referenced, prefix it by the alias of the target table, like `component_number_id` becoming `cnr_id` with `cnr` as alias for `component_numbers`.

## Active revision

There are various methods. Most often seen: active_flag. Requires business rule to validate that only one can be valid per component_number_id. That can be done client side, database side using a unique key constraint (depends on database platform, SQL Server and Oracle have different semantics for null values and a unique key) or database side using triggers.

Alternative implementation is to maintain table components_active. When component_id occurs in that table, it is active. UK ensures at most one component_number_id. Depending on your platform, you will need to duplicate component_number_id into that table which introduces extra code to maintain it.

Comment: hi @user1930587 Did this help solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?